# Intel Edison not Booting

Tags: boot, intel-edison

I have a new Intel Edison connected to the Arduino breakout board and it is unable to boot. I have never seen it boot ever.

I have tried connecting it with different settings to discard a problem at cable level or power input.

The current setup is:
-Intel Edison mounted on Arduino breakout board.
-Power cable connected to Powered USB Hub or to wall adapter.
-Console cable connected directly to computer USB port.

When monitoring the boot process with a terminal app, the only output is:

---

PSH KERNEL VERSION: b0182727

..WR: 20104000

---

SCU IPC: 0x800000d0  0xfffce92c

PSH miaHOB version: TNG..B0..VVBD..0000000c

microkernel. built 23:15:13. Apr 24 2014.

******* PSH loader *******

PCM page cache size = 192 KB

Cache Constraint = 0 Pages

Arming IPC driver ..

Adding page store pool ..

PagestoreAddr(IMR Start Address) = 0x04899000

pageStoreSize(IMR Size)          = 0x00080000

**** Ready to receive application ****

After this, the Edison loops every X amount of time. If I disconnect and reconnect power, the exact result is obtained.

I have also tried to boot from OsX / Debian / Linux with no results.

When running the flashall.sh scripts, the device is never found.

I have tried everything I have found online, and have run out of ideas...

Comment: I would try flashing with the dev kit installer instead if you haven't tried that yet, for Mac: https://downloadmirror.intel.com/25384/eng/m_iot_dev_kit_2015.0.026.tar.gz and if you want another OS: https://software.intel.com/en-us/iot/hardware/edison/downloads

Comment: I had already tried that, with the following result: The Intel® Edison is not connected. Make sure your Intel® Edison is set up and connected

Comment: And both USB cables are connected?

Comment: Yes. Both cables are connected.

Comment: I have actually tried every type of cable.

Answer (score 0):

I am now sure the Edison has a physical problem. I tried with a new one and was able to boot it up without any trouble. I already talked to the company I bought it from and they will be doing a refund.